# I am using a MIT licensed module in a closed source project. What are my obligations?

Tags: licensing, mit

I am using diverse module under the MIT license in my project. The project consist of a webserver, which will be closed source, commercial, and will not be distributed.

As I understand the MIT license, if I were to distribute the code, I just need to keep the license in the code.

However, I will not distribute the code, so am I just free to do as I see fit? Do I need to include "About" section that give you the MIT license alongside which project I used internally? Or is there other obligations I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are coding a webserver, even if the webserver itself will not be redistributed you still need to consider JavaScript and related assets that are effectively redistributed to your users' browsers.

If this is strictly backend code using an MIT license, you have no special obligations beyond [this](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT):

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Note that there are many variants of the MIT license but most are just minor variations and this attribution requirement will be the same.

> I will not distribute the code, so am I just free to do as I see fit?

Yes.

> Do I need to include "About" section that give you the MIT license alongside which project I used internally?

No, though it would be nice.

> Or are there other obligations I missed?`

No.