# I m interested in package on GITHUB - what are my rights and what should i do?

Tags: licensing, github

i m thinking on making browser game and would like to start it on ready made code.

For example https://github.com/FrankProjects/UltimateWarfare if i would pick this one. ..

I know that i would need to include that MIT license on my project.

But the question is do my project that would be based on example above have to be open source at the end?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I m new too licensing and GITHUB so please try to hep me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [I am using a MIT licensed module in a closed source project. What are my obligations?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/i-am-using-a-mit-licensed-module-in-a-closed-source-project-what-are-my-obligat)

Comment: @Brandin Ok but. .. I m still not quite sure. .. At the end i will need to publish my code as open source or it isn't necessary?

Comment: There's nothing in the MIT license that requires you to publish your own code as open source.

Comment: @Brandin Even if the main part of source is from that opensource code?

Comment: Love these -1 without telling me why ..  Can i get some more?

Comment: Just because I left a comment doesn't mean I am giving you -1. If it makes you feel better I'll give you +1. You could improve this by putting in more research effort to your question to make it more useful for other people that see this in the future.

Comment: @Brandin Just so you know i was not targeting that to you but overall :) I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not have to make your own project open source.

The only requirement is that you keep the MIT license information of the original project intact and that you send it along with any binary distributions of your project (with the indication that the MIT license applies only to the original project).

Comment: Even if the main part of source is from that opensource code?

Comment: @Ingus, yes even if the main part is taken from that other project.